# NoMethodError when using @package as a variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model named Package and this code lives in Admin::PackagesController.

```
def new
  @package = Package.new
end
```

This throws a NoMethodError with the message "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass", highlighting the line where @package is defined.

This same error does not occur when I use another name for the variable, or when I run the same line in the Rails console.

This is on Rails 4. The entire code for the controller is below.

```
class Admin::PackagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @packages = Package.all
  end

  def new
    @package = Package.new
  end

  def create
    @package = Package.new(package_params)
    if @package.save
      flash[:success] = "Package created."
      redirect_to admin_packages_path
    else
      flash.now[:warning] = "Something went wrong."
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @package = Package.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @package = Package.find(params[:id])
    if @package.update_attributes(package_params)
      flash[:success] = "Package updated."
      redirect_to admin_packages_path
    else
      flash.now[:warning] = "Something went wrong."
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @package = Package.find(params[:id])
    @package.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Package deleted."
    redirect_to admin_packages_path
  end    

  private
    def package_params
      params.require(:package).permit(:name, :price, :class, :description, :order)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed in your "package_params" you seem to have an attribute called class. Class is a pretty bad name to use for attributes in Ruby/Rails. That's probably the problem.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Thanks! Migrated!